# Can Windows power manager stop SYS HDD, if it is not in use?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am running a windows 2008 server and trying to manage its power such that the *system drive* should stop if not used for 10 min. My all of other power settings including on my backup drive work except this one and same is behavior on my Win 7 workstation.
Is it something blocked by the OS or I am doing some mistake?

Comment: Probably, something *is* using the drive in the background. Either way, this is more of a question for Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice there is no way to specify the OS drive.  If you set windows to power down disks after 10 mins windows will power down any unutilized disk.  If it's not powering it down it's because it's being used.

Comment: +1, ALso, your hard drive will almost certainly last longer if it does not power up/down con a regular basis. Each power up/down cycle causes a heat cycle, which causes all the various parts to expand and contract; not good for longevity.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jim B and Chris S that it is in use, and that is (usually) a good thing on servers. If however you wanted to pursue the "what exactly is using the disk" question, then [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a filter on PATH should get you the information you need.